# The right way to translate "Safe Withdrawal Rate"

Tags: перевод

I'm struggling to find a proper translation of "Safe Withdrawal Rate" concept. This basically means the percentage of your initial portfolio that you can withdraw each year (usually adjusted for inflation) without risking to deplete it.

Here's what I have so far:

- Безопасная норма изъятия
- Безопасный уровень расходов (*not really correct, but sounds better to me*)
- Безопасная ставка вывода средств
- Безопасный коэффициент снятия средств
- Безопасный процент вывода
- Безопасная скорость снятия
- and any combination of the above

I may be missing something, so any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The most popular term (if "popular" is even applicable for a terminology from quite narrow domain) is **`ставка ежегодного изъятия из портфеля`** - or just "ставка изъятия из портфеля" (since it does not necessarily should happen annually); - [like in](https://a2-finance.com/posts/1527666433-pravilo-4):

> Что, если бы это было не так сложно? А если бы история показала нам,
> что есть что-то, называемое ставкой ежегодного изъятия из портфеля
> (Safe Withdrawal Rate)? И что эта SWR равна примерно 4% от стоимости
> вашего портфеля?

or [here](https://zen.yandex.ru/media/labat/pravilo-vyhoda-na-pensiiu-ili-skolko-mojno-tratit-deneg-ot-kapitala-chtoby-on-ne-umenshalsia-5d69f610028d6800ac249378):

> Методом сравнительного анализа он вывел безопасный процент вывода
> денег. Ставка ежегодного изъятия из портфеля получила название SWR
> (Safe Withdrawal Rate).

Слово `ставка` иногда взаимозаменяемо с `размер`, поэтому "размер [ежегодного] изъятия" тоже встречается.

Comment: Thank you! The domain is indeed quite narrow.
This answer actually sounds good. I'm still not sure if it's appropriate to skip word "safe" here. If we just add it, we get "Безопасная ставка изъятия [из портфеля]", which is one of the translations I'm considering.